# How to create a solid black shadow behind text in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, illustration, drop-shadow

How do you create this text effect in Illustrator?

I tried creating a shadow behind the letter, but it did not appear similar to this.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't get that with the Drop Shadow effect, but instead:

- Select your original T shape
- Do an offset via `Object → Path → Offset Path`
- Create a copy of the offset shape and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Drag</kbd> diagonally
- Create an `Object → Blend` between these 2 offset shapes with 'Specified Distance' set to 0

[image]